# What are the most prominent Tibetan Buddhist texts that are only written in Tibetan script?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, texts, tibetan

A lot of Buddhist texts come from Sanskrit or Chinese. I am looking at the Kangyur and Tengyur, and a few scattered others. But a lot of those are from Sanskrit and Chinese as well (or other languages, Pali, etc.). What books or groups of books/works can only be found in Tibetan script? *Whether or not it has been translated to other languages isn't important, the original language should be Tibetan though.*

I am trying to mentally gather an image of how much reading would be required to gain the knowledge unique to Tibetan Buddhism.

Answer (score 1):

The foundational tantra (book) of Tibetan Dzogchen , the Dra Thalgyur, (“The Reverberation of Sound”) is only available in Tibetan. If you are interested in the highest practice in Tibetan Buddhism, that would be one you would need to read.

Comment: That is [སྒྲ་ཐལ་འགྱུར](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverberation_of_Sound) according to Wikipedia, can its Tibetan content be found online anywhere in copy/pastable format? Is it found in the [Kangyur somewhere](https://adarsha.dharma-treasure.org/kdbs/degekangyur?locale=bo)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the local university library. In the city I live there is some; just go see the Administration for a security pass first to avoid any security issues as a campus visitor. Since state collages collaborate in research; your local state university should have some as well... might want to call it first and find out; if not the largest city nearest public library should have some.

Checking them out in University not really possible unless you are a student however there are reading rooms. Public library offers a card... those can be checked out; but they too have reading rooms if distraction is a problem elsewhere.

Some colleges have their entire library and even college courses uploaded like Harvard has been doing allowing anyone to sit in on classes free as if you were a student since it is "free" it is unaccredited meaning you wont get a degree but at least you can learn it so if you attend elsewhere then it is a great primer to already know whatever it is before you take it.

So going to college library websites might be just the ticket to the quality texts you are looking for.

Translations haven't ever been good... like when watching Anime Japanese to English is the funniest like old lip syncing Kung Fu movies... There is a song in one anime that says: when you pick me up my soul feels free... As the translation. When the actual words are: Your smiling eyes embraced my heart.
Huge difference and how those two phrases are synonymous? Not in the slightest.

Just sitting like immersion in shunyata one will be like a cup or bowl and pick up the entire whatever it is like accumulation... if one leaves all formation alone is shunyata as all mental aggregates fall on the potters wheel when the senses are grasped at resulting in moving the mind/turning the wheel; instead of sitting the mind so it becomes filled when that link of becoming makes it's round.